# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' in IPython.Display

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

in the

```
from IPython.display import HTML
```

it says "AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'" I don't understand, someone have a solution for this?

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in <module>
    import resource
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\Documents\first-order\python system\load images.py", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython.display import HTML
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.timing import clock, clock2
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\shiboken2\files.dir\shibokensupport\__feature__.py", line 142, in _import
    return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jpdyb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
    clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: What version of IPython are you using?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of the error and traceback.

Comment: idk how to see the version

Comment: c'mon answer plz

Comment: From an interactive prompt, run `import IPython; print(IPython.__version__)`

Comment: it shows the same error

Comment: How did you install IPython?

Comment: pip install IPython

Comment: OK, try `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall IPython` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: The root of the problem is that "clock" was removed from Python (quite a while ago), and you have an ancient version of IPython that doesn't know it.    And this is not an interactive chat service.  Do NOT demand instant help.

Comment: it dont worked @Tim Roberts

Comment: Don't know what to tell you.  This problem was fixed in IPython 10 years ago, so you have some antique.  You may have to fetch this from their git repository and install it yourself.

Comment: but i used "pip install" not git